# Is there any reliable way to get the data from PostgreSQL according to the user interest in the Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

Our Project is similar in functionality to Twitter
We want to show the posts on the feed according to the user's interest based on the user's likes, shares, and comments on the posts

1. how and where we can save the user's activities?
2. how we can filter and get the post data using the Django QuerySet and DRF paginations for a user
3. how we can sort the post data with the recent + interest-related data

**if there is any better approach that exists, then please share some details about it.**

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: In my opinion the best way is to write your own algorithm for the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

```
This is a standard personalization/recommendation use case, and there are a few standard approaches:

Content-based filtering: select posts that are similar to ones the user has interacted with. You can use techniques like TF-IDF to calculate a similarity score between posts.
Collaborative filtering: select posts that people with a similar activity history to the user have interacted with.

Typically you would precalculate recommendation scores in a background job, and store them in a separate table. Then when showing a feed to a user, you just ORDER BY the score column to prioritize recommended posts.
You can combine the two approaches by taking a weighted average of content-based and collaborative scores.
Note that all of this assumes you have a adequate volume of data and activity to make the recommendations useful. For a new site with few users it may be better to just show chronological posts initially.
```